# Read an Excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using [Bytescout](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html) to read an excel file.

```
 Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet();
 document.LoadFromFile("myFile.xlsx");
 var ds = document.ExportToDataSet();
 var dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

C# can't read some columns in the the table, it displays non numeric instead of the value. This columns have an excel formulas.

Do you have any idea how can I fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give an example of one of these files?

Comment: What does _"it displays non numeric"_ mean? What is the cell's type? What does the formula evaluate to?

Comment: @ LegionMammal978 how can i attach a file to my question ?

Comment: it contains string, these columns are a result of a conctinating of 2 columns using a formulas.

Comment: It likely has to do with Bytescout.  Have you tried one of the other readers?  It seems like there are a dozen of them out there.

Comment: I have just removed the formulas, and it worked fine. Do you no a reader which allows to retrieve the dataset in 3 line of code ?

Comment: @BilelChaouadi can you please email more information (what are exact values of these cells etc) to support@bytescout.com ? There could be a bug in mapping types from spreadsheet to dataset

Comment: @ Eugene As I said, it s a string, these column is a result of formulas which concatenates 2 columns, I saved the file as values ( without any formulas) and it worked fine